# "Unknown Host" - Connecting to PostgreSQL database in SQL Shell (Windows)

Tags: windows, postgresql, shell

I've previously been using PostgreSQL in Ubuntu using:

```
$sudo -i -u postgres
```

to access postgres through the terminal to create a role and database. And then able to log in and make changes using:

```
$sudo -u [dbname] psql
```

However now I need to use PostgreSQL with LabVIEW so I've had to download PostgreSQL on a Windows PC. I can access the database through Pgadmin and have created a database but when I go into SQL shell it comes up with:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with roles, as I haven't created one for the windows database. But I can't even get past the above to create a role or make any changes in the command prompt.

When I type my computer host name, it says

```
    psql: could not translate host name "Lisa" to address: Unknown host
```

It says I am connected on PgAdmin and I am able to create databases and tables through the interface, but I can't figure out how to access it in the SQL Shell (psql).

Comment: Don't put "solved" into the title of the question. Accept the answer - that will mark this question as solved.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Entered server as localhost IP.

```
    Server [localhost]: 127.0.0.1 
    Database [localhost]: [dbname]
    Port [5432]: 5432
    Username [postgres]: [username]
```